# How do I mention a video game in a formal piece of writing?

Tags: punctuation, titles

What is the proper convention for mentioning the title of a video game in a formal research paper? Would I place the title in quotations, like the name of a short story ("Myst"), underline it, like the title of a book, or italicize it (*Myst*)? I would prefer an answer backed up by a formal standard such as MLA, APA, Chicago, or AP, if they cover this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Diana Hacker's *Research and Documentation* (Bedford-St. Martin's), the [MLA citation](http://bcs.bedfordstmartins.com/resdoc5e/RES5e_ch08_s1-0011.html#RES5e_ch08_p0486) for a video game should follow this format:

[image]

From the same source, the [APA citation](http://bcs.bedfordstmartins.com/resdoc5e/RES5e_ch09_s1-0002.html#RES5e_ch09_p0374) for a video game should follow this format:

[image]

(You can't tell from the example of Sims 2, but in an APA citation, only the first word of a title is capitalized. Therefore, Call of Duty would be listed as Call of duty.

These are the formats for a Works Cited/References entry. In the text itself, the title of the video game should be capitalized and italicized, just as the title of a book would be.

Answer (score 1):

The APA does in fact cover this, though under the broader category of "software."

In text, the title of the video game should **NOT** be italicized (p. 210). When citing the video game, you'd use the following convention:

> Copyright Holder (Year of Publication). Game Title [Software]. Location of Producer: Producer.

Note that Copyright Holder and Producer may be the same.

Source: APA manual, 6th edition. I'll confirm with MLA and Chicago when I get home.

Comment: OP, thanks for accepting my answer, but please see the revised answer! I left out the most important word, "not." The titles should not be capitalized. For added reference, I included the page number.

Answer (score 1):

Chicago Manual of Style 8.190. In running text video game titles are italicized.

Answer (score -1):

According to [this blog post](https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2015/01/how-to-cite-software-in-apa-style.html), you simply capitalize the title when writing it in-text. The citation style in the previous two answers appears correct.